# Issue using custom sign in with Apple | SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, apple-sign-in

Essentially the goal is to create a custom sign in with apple button. The following is what I have so far, the code compiles fine and the prompt to login shows up as expected but after logging in appleIDCredential does not return any values, name, email, etc. all nil. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import SwiftUI
import AuthenticationServices

class AppleSignInHandler: NSObject, ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate, ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding {
    func presentationAnchor(for controller: ASAuthorizationController) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
         // Return the first window in the current window scene as the presentation anchor for the ASAuthorizationController
         return UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
             .first { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
             .map { $0 as? UIWindowScene }
             .flatMap { $0?.windows.first } ?? UIApplication.shared.windows.first!
     }


    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
        if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
            // Apple Sign In was successful.
            // You can now use the `appleIDCredential` to authenticate the user in your app.
            let userFullName = appleIDCredential
            print("Apple Sign In was successful. User's full name is: \(userFullName)")
        }
    }

    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
        // Apple Sign In failed.
        // You can handle the error here.
        print("Apple Sign In failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

struct CustomAppleSignInButton: View {
    let appleSignInHandler = AppleSignInHandler()
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            // Perform the Apple Sign In process here
            let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
            let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
            request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]

            let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
            authorizationController.delegate = appleSignInHandler
            authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = appleSignInHandler
            authorizationController.performRequests()
        }) {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "apple.logo")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 26, height: 32)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("black"))
                Text("Continue With Apple")
                    .foregroundColor(Color("black"))
            }
            .padding()
            .frame(width: 340, height: 55)
            .background(Color(.label))
            .cornerRadius(28)
        }
    }
}


struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CustomAppleSignInButton()
    }
}
```

Comment: Name and email are only available the very first time a user logs in, when they are creating the account.

Comment: @loremipsum What is available on login? Any values?

Comment: Just the ID in the credential watch the WWDC related videos.

Comment: Got it, is using nonce really needed? This script works without it

Comment: Only you can answer that question. You should read more about it.